# 'row-id = [object Object]' in ag-grid, duplicate node id issue

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I get a warning in the console because `row-id = [object Object]` in ag-grid.

> ag-grid: duplicate node id '[object Object]' detected from
>   getRowNodeId callback, this could cause issues in your grid.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Comment: share your code for more specific help

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `getRowNodeId` property. You might have provided it inappropriately.

Sample Reference: [Adding the Data Table](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-redux-integration-pt1/#adding-the-data-table)

```
        <AgGridReact
            // provide column definitions
            columnDefs={this.colDefs}
            // row data provided via props from the file store
            rowData={this.props.files}
            // return id required for delta updates
            getRowNodeId={data => data.id}>
        </AgGridReact>
```

[ag-grid](/questions/tagged/ag-grid) Docs reference: [Grid callbacks](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-callbacks/)

> ***getRowNodeId(data):*** Allows you to set the id for a particular row node based on the data. Useful for selection and server side sorting and filtering for paging and virtual pagination.

Comment: Thanks! this worked. I did mention it incorrectly in my code.

Comment: You can accept this as answer if this worked for you